# Every unital algebra of dimension 2 is a quadratic algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $E$ an $A$-algebra with basis $(e_1,e_2)$ and unit element $e=\lambda e_1+\mu e_2$. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be the ideal generated by $(\lambda,\mu)$. Then $\mathfrak{a}=A$ and so there exist $\alpha,\beta\in A$ such that $1=\alpha\lambda+\beta\mu$. Write $u:=\beta e_1-\alpha e_2$. I want to show that $(e,u)$ is a basis of $E$.

**Independence:** Let $\xi,\eta\in A$ such that $\xi e+\eta u=0$. Then $\xi\lambda e_1+\xi\mu e_2+\eta\beta e_1-\eta\alpha e_2=0$ and so $(\xi\lambda+\eta\beta)e_1+(\xi\mu-\eta\alpha)e_2=0$. It follows that $$\xi\lambda+\eta\beta=0\text{ and }\xi\mu-\eta\alpha=0.$$
I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any suggestions?

**Generating**: Let $x\in E$. Then $x=ex$ and $x=1x$. Thus $x=(\lambda e_1+\mu e_2)x$ and $x=(\alpha\lambda+\beta\mu)x$. Again, I am not sure where to go from here. Hints?

I also know that $E/\mathfrak{a}E\cong\{0\}$ and so $E=\mathfrak{a}E=\{\sum_{\alpha,x}\xi_{\alpha,x}(\alpha x)\ |\ \xi\in\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathfrak{a}\times E)}\}$. But I don't know if I can use this fact.

Comment: The determinant of the transition matrix for your four elements is $al+bm=1$, so it sends a basis to a basis.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you, yes that works. Is there another route which doesn't use determinants?

Comment: It seems the best route to me, so I haven't thought of another one. :)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff okay, fair enough.